# Could not provision the RemoteApp collection. Error: Could not register the endpoint

Tags: azure

Created a new hybrid collection in Australia East utilising an existing VNet subnet. We are using NSG's on the subnet.

Uploaded the Template Image. The Template image had additional Windows Updates installed since using it in another collection in another Azure location which isn't using a VNet. Otherwise it is identical.

The collection was showing as Provisioning when I left for the day. Return today to find the error:
Could not provision the RemoteApp collection. Error: Could not register the endpoint.

I went to the QuickStart section, 'join local domain' and 'link a template image' where green.

Clicked 'join local domain' and re-entered the password which was blank.
This became grey.

Clicked 'link a template image', Selected 'Link an existing template image'
Selected the Template Image from the list which I had uploaded yesterday.
Clicked Complete.

The collection status changed to Updating.

Eventually this error appeared:
Could not provision the RemoteApp collection. Error: Internal Server Error

There appears to be no further error detail. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only solution that would work for you is to delete the entire collection and recreate it.
Try it and tell me whether it worked for you or not :)

Comment: Well, I think I have no other way to go through. Thank you so much

Comment: saw this happening many times and the only thing i had to do was trying again. eventually it Works. Sometimes i had this error for a day and the next day it all gone.